# Netsuite Role Cannot Access all Records in Center and Scripts Not Running

Tags: netsuite

I created a new role in Netsuite, and assigned some records to it. I then created a center for this role/these 3 records. If I am in my account (the owner of the records), I am able to see all three record types. If I sign into any other user account with the role (even if they also have an admin role), I am only able to see one of the record types. I have checked the records, role, and users and everything looks consistent, so I am not sure why other users aren't able to see anything. When I am using another user, I am also unable to get custom scripts to run (suitescript). The scripts are in a released status. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured out what it was. For each script deployment, All Roles (or whatever roles you specifically need) need to be specifically granted rights to run the script.

For seeing the records, either the record needs to be changed to use no permissions, or the role needs to have the "Custom Record Entries" permission on the lists tab added.

Comment: Thanks for the help! spent hours trying to figure it out